# Is burnination a [niche-area]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

Do we need the [niche-area](/questions/tagged/niche-area) tag (6 questions, with half of them closed or marked as a dupe, no tag wiki) here on Meta Stack Exchange? I question its utility for two reasons:

- It's not really possible for someone to be an expert in niche areas. One can be an expert in a specific niche area, or even a small collection of them, but someone who is an expert in the intricacies of the past tenses of Sumerian verbs might not be expected to have any specific level of competency in trebuchet repair.
- The tag appears to be used for two separate things:

  - Niche tags on a site (concepts that are on-topic, but are not popular or frequently discussed) and how their use or moderation differs from high-volume tags
  - The quantum of specialization necessary to support an *independent* Stack Exchange site

Do we really need this tag? If not, is it too much of a niche area for us to go ahead and burninate it?

Most questions about niche-area tags can simply be tagged [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) along with any other applicable tag (e.g. [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions), [edits](/questions/tagged/edits), [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) or [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close)). Questions about how to handle specific niche-area tags (e.g. how to encourage more people to review [cobol] questions on Stack Overflow) will often be better asked on the applicable per-site meta.

Questions about new site specialization can be tagged [area51](/questions/tagged/area51).

Comment: Agreed. It's too vague to be synonimized to another tag and not useful enough to stick around. Make it go.

Comment: Having said that, can't we fix this with a simple re-tagging operation?

Comment: @mast yes, but I wanted to seek the consensus of the community before I went ahead and did it to all those questions.

Comment: Can whoever downvotes this proposal comment on why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes.

This can be fixed with a simple retagging quest. I've taken care of half of those 6 for you, feel free to do the other 3. Don't forget to check if the rest of the question needs a touch-up as well, although with closed questions that's less of a concern.

[niche-area](/questions/tagged/niche-area) is too vague to be synonimized to another tag and is not useful enough to stick around. No point in keeping it: clean it up. It wasn't used much anyway, so it should stay gone for a while.